# Composite Control Textbox defaults control name when dropped on a form

Tags: vb.net, custom-controls

I have a user control that consists of a panel, with a textbox in it.  I have overridden the Text property of the UserControl, so that I can expose the Text property of the TextBox.

```
  <BindableAttribute(False)>
  <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Browsable(True), _
   DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible), DefaultValue("")>
  Public Overrides Property Text() As String
    Get
      Return txtText.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
      txtText.Text = value
    End Set
  End Property
```

This works, and I am able to set the Text value in the TextBox by using the property.  The problem I am having is, when I add the control to a form, the name of the control ends up in the TextBox.  Each time I add this control to the form, I need to manually go to the Text property and delete the value.  I am looking for a way to override that behavior.  When I add the control to a form, I want the Text value to be String.Empty.

Any ideas?  I've spent a few hours looking around, and I can't find anything.  A lot of the threads I've found around have had to do with ASP.NET.  This is standard windows forms that I'm working with.

Thanks

Comment: This is the default behavior.  Plop a new Label on your form and the Name == Text; add a new GroupBox and the Name ==  Text.  NET overrides it when a new TextBox is created, but with a UC that was done long ago when you added it to the UC canvas.

Comment: Right.  In the case of the TextBox, you can see the name flash in the newly added TextBox, before it disappears.  I'm going to give the idea below a try tomorrow, and see how it works.  You'd think that there'd be a way to override this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Name` and `Text` are two different properties!

`Name` will result in something like `controlname1`. Maybe you have set the `Text` property of the TextBox to `"TextBox"` inside the UserControl inadvertently. Delete it there!

---

**UPDATE**

It seems that the WinForms designer is adding this text on its own. 
You can solve the problem like this:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class UserControl1
    Private _designMode As Boolean

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        _designMode = LicenseManager.UsageMode = LicenseUsageMode.Designtime
    End Sub

    <BindableAttribute(False)> _
    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Browsable(True), _
      DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible), _
      DefaultValue("")> _
    Public Overrides Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return txtText.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If Not _designMode OrElse _
               Not Regex.IsMatch(value, Me.GetType().Name & "\d+") Then
                txtText.Text = value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

The text is not set if we are in design mode and the value corresponds to the control name plus a number. This ensures that you can still set a text at design time. If you do not need to set a text at design time, you can drop the Regex part of the condition.

Comment: I understand that they're different properties.  This control is very basic.  The only place that the .Text property is in the code that I included above.  If I comment out txtEdit.Text = value in the Set, then the name of the control is not in the TextBox.  I think that this has something to do with what happens when you add a new user control to a form.  Sometimes, the Text property is set to the name of the control.  For instance, if I drop a GroupBox, the caption for it will be GroupBox1.  The caption is the Text property.  I thought overriding the property would get rid of this.

Comment: What I want to say is: open the UserControl in the designer, select the TextBox and see whether its `Text` property is empty (in the property grid). If it is empty, you should be able to drop your UserControls on a form and they sould remain empty.

Comment: The Text property is empty.  I feel like it is something that VB is doing, in spite of the overridden Text property.  If instead of Text, I create a property named TextValue, and use that to get and set the value in the TextBox, then it works just fine.  It is only a problem with using the overridden Text property.